Error loading FFmpeg: ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined - Angular 18.2.3
Question:
I am working on an Angular project (version 18.2.3) where I use ffmpeg.wasm to trim videos and extract frames. However, when trying to load FFmpeg, I am encountering the following error in the console:
Error loading FFmpeg: ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not definedenter image description here

Below is the code that initializes FFmpeg and attempts to load it: 

export class VideoEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
  isPlaying = false;
  frameDataArray: Uint8Array[] = [];
  frameIndex = 0;

  async trimAndExtractFrames(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      // Load FFmpeg
      await this.ffmpeg.load();
      console.log("FFmpeg loaded successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading FFmpeg:", error);
    }
  }
}

I have tried to troubleshoot the issue but am unsure how to proceed.
The error seems related to SharedArrayBuffer, which I understand is required for performance improvements in multi-threading for web applications.
I have checked my ffmpeg.wasm setup, and it works fine in a plain JavaScript application.
Ensured that my Angular application is correctly serving the WebAssembly files.
Looked into setting up the appropriate HTTP headers for Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy, but I am unsure if I have done it correctly.
My questions:

How do I resolve the SharedArrayBuffer is not defined error in Angular?
Is there a specific setup required for using SharedArrayBuffer in Angular with WebAssembly applications like FFmpeg?
How can I ensure that the necessary HTTP headers are configured correctly in my Angular project to support this?

Additional information:

Angular version: 18.2.3
ffmpeg.wasm version: Latest (installed via npm)
Browser: Chrome 100+


I tried launching Chrome with the flags you mentioned:
On Windows:
chrome.exe --enable-features=SharedArrayBuffer --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:/ChromeDev"

On macOS:
open -na "Google Chrome" --args --enable-features=SharedArrayBuffer --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/tmp/tempChrome

Using these flags successfully bypassed the security restrictions and allowed SharedArrayBuffer to work. However, I understand that this approach disables certain security features, so I will only use it in my local development environment for testing purposes.
For anyone else facing a similar issue, it's important to note that these flags should not be used in production environments due to the potential security risks.

you might also check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer#security_requirements
